# Unicode escape is ctrl+[ , why does this work in terminal or vim, but not safari or other parts of OS?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, keybindings, vi

When i'm working in VIM i'll often times use ctrl+[ to exit insert mode.  But if i need to press escape in other parts of the OS ctrl+[ does not act the same way as escape.

For example if search a page in safari you can't escape out of the search with ctrl+[

can anyone shed light why this is and possibly tell if it's possible to get ctrl+[ to always be escape with out custom plugins or weird 3rd party software?

Comment: What does Unicode have to do with this?  Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example if search a page in safari you can't escape out of the search with ctrl+[

It's because Safari is not operating in an ASCII/ANSI Terminal environment.

The [Escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character) is

- octal: `\033`
- hexadecimal: `\x1B` or `^[`
- decimal: 27

It's just a series of characters the *terminal* looks for that interprets it as actions or special characters.

As for working in vim (or vi), you aren't limited to sending `^[` (<kbd>^ Control</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>), you can simply press the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key.  It will do the same thing.